# Java - RichFaces - RTL

Tags: jsf, right-to-left

I'm looking for Java "Faces" that supports RTL (Right To Left) user interfaces. The only library that I've checked so far is [RichFaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richfaces). It seems that it doesn't support it natively.

What is a good resource that talks about this issue?

What other "Faces" can be recommend that natively support RTL user interfaces?

Answer (score 4):

RichFaces components support the `dir` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The JSF standard components already do it since ages. They just supports all of the HTML attribues, including the `dir` attribute, which you can set to `"rtl"`. I would be surprised if any of the 3rd party component libraries didn't inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

In richfaces, it does support dir="rtl" in all components, yep it does not say you can not set the attribute dir **but when you put it on, it will not display correct.** To do so, in richfaces you need override its style, replacing left with right and right with left, i have checked it for simple components but for others like tree, like menu it would not be easy as i say. I have no idea what other components would support that.

btw i speak for 3.1.5. GA.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't used it on my own, but was just googling about it and wikipedia states it might be candidate:
http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/